# Alternaitive function to Matlab's esort.m

Tags: matlab

I need to sort a vector of eigenvectors Ev (obtained from  [Ev, Ed] = eig (A)) in descending order. I also need indices used in the sort.

I cannot use esort.m which comes with the controls system toolbox (which I don't have and cannot get). Is there an alternative function to esort.m which I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `sort`, `real` and `imag` you can "copy" the `esort` function:

```
imre = rand(10,1)+rand(10,1)*1i; %random imaginary number

re = real(imre);                 %extract the real part
im = imag(imre)*1i;              %extract the imaginary part

[sorted,ind] = sort(re);         %sort according to the real part
imre_sort = sorted+im(ind);      %add the imaginary part.
```

So simply a function similar to:

```
function imre_sort = todelete(imre,ord)
%ord can be 'ascend' or 'descend'
    if nargin == 1
        ord = 'ascend';
    end

    re = real(imre);
    im = imag(imre)*1i;

    [sorted,ind] = sort(re,ord);
    imre_sort = sorted+im(ind); 

end
```